# org.hibernate.MappingException: The increment size of the sequence is set to [10] in the entity mapping while ... size is [1]

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, id-generation

We run into a problem when updating to Spring Boot 2.2 and the associated Hibernate 5.4.x.

We do have the following sequence generator

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "hilo_sequence_generator")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "hilo_sequence_generator",
        strategy = "...",
        parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "XXX_SEQUENCE"),
                @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "10"),
                @Parameter(name = "optimizer", value = "hilo")
        })
private Long id;
```

With the update to SB 2.2 / HB 5.4 we get the following initialization error

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: The increment size of the sequence is set to [10] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1]
```

The DB sequence increment size is 1:

```
                    Sequence "...xxx_sequence"
  Type  | Start | Minimum |       Maximum       | Increment | Cycles? | Cache
--------+-------+---------+---------------------+-----------+---------+-------
 bigint |     1 |       1 | 9223372036854775807 |         1 | no      |     1
```

However, to my understanding the (soft) increment size of the hilo algorithm has nothing to do with the (hard) increment size of the DB.

Is this an error in HB or can we circumvent the problem somehow?

WRT to the questions of Jens:

- Sequence is generated by Liquibase:

  ```
  <changeSet author="GerdAschemann (generated)" id="1540300079577-1">
      <createSequence sequenceName="rbl_sequence"/>
  </changeSet>
  ```
- It happens during Application context setup/Bean initialization:

  ```
  2019-12-12 18:29:52.841  INFO 20076 --- [           main] o.h.j.i.u.LogHelper                      : {} HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
  2019-12-12 18:29:52.971  INFO 20076 --- [           main] o.h.Version                              : {} HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.9.Final}
  2019-12-12 18:29:53.127  INFO 20076 --- [           main] o.h.a.c.Version                          : {} HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
  2019-12-12 18:29:53.320  INFO 20076 --- [           main] o.h.d.Dialect                            : {} HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
  2019-12-12 18:29:53.962 ERROR 20076 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatStarter                : {} Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchDeleteEndpointConfiguration' defined in file [R:\codebase\reisebegleitung\app\app-guide\target\classes\de\db\vendo\rbl\guide\adapter\maintenanceEndpoint\BatchDeleteEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'maintenanceApplication' defined in file [R:\codebase\reisebegleitung\app\app-guide\target\classes\de\db\vendo\rbl\guide\application\MaintenanceApplication.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'reisekettenRepositoryImpl' defined in file [R:\codebase\reisebegleitung\app\app-guide\target\classes\de\db\vendo\rbl\guide\adapter\domainJpa\ReisekettenRepositoryImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reisekettenJpaRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5b430541' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5b430541': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=de.db.vendo.rbl.guide.adapter.domainJpa.entity.SubscriptionRetryEntity]
  2019-12-12 18:29:53.994  INFO 20076 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.StandardService                  : {} Stopping service [Tomcat]
  ```
- Disabling validation does not change anything
- Added a sample project to GH: https://github.com/ascheman/hibernate-so-59305427
- Stack trace:

  ```
  2019-12-13 11:58:33.245  INFO 16796 --- [           main] n.a.d.s.b.h.HibernateProblemApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
  2019-12-13 11:58:33.773  INFO 16796 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
  2019-12-13 11:58:33.858  INFO 16796 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 76ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
  2019-12-13 11:58:34.194  INFO 16796 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
  2019-12-13 11:58:34.282  INFO 16796 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
  2019-12-13 11:58:35.149  INFO 16796 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
  2019-12-13 11:58:35.157  INFO 16796 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))
  2019-12-13 11:58:35.162  INFO 16796 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
  2019-12-13 11:58:35.165  INFO 16796 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : DELETE FROM PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
  2019-12-13 11:58:35.166  INFO 16796 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : INSERT INTO PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID, LOCKED) VALUES (1, FALSE)
  2019-12-13 11:58:35.169  INFO 16796 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT LOCKED FROM PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK WHERE ID=1
  2019-12-13 11:58:35.176  INFO 16796 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Successfully acquired change log lock
  2019-12-13 11:58:36.825  INFO 16796 --- [           main] l.c.StandardChangeLogHistoryService      : Creating database history table with name: PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
  2019-12-13 11:58:36.826  INFO 16796 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED INT NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM VARCHAR(35), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), COMMENTS VARCHAR(255), TAG VARCHAR(255), LIQUIBASE VARCHAR(20), CONTEXTS VARCHAR(255), LABELS VARCHAR(255), DEPLOYMENT_ID VARCHAR(10))
  2019-12-13 11:58:36.827  INFO 16796 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
  2019-12-13 11:58:36.827  INFO 16796 --- [           main] l.c.StandardChangeLogHistoryService      : Reading from PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
  2019-12-13 11:58:36.827  INFO 16796 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT * FROM PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC
  2019-12-13 11:58:36.828  INFO 16796 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
  2019-12-13 11:58:36.833  INFO 16796 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : CREATE SEQUENCE PUBLIC.xxx_sequence
  2019-12-13 11:58:36.835  INFO 16796 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet            : Sequence xxx_sequence created
  2019-12-13 11:58:36.835  INFO 16796 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.xxx_entity (id BIGINT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT kunde_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id))
  2019-12-13 11:58:36.836  INFO 16796 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet            : Table xxx_entity created
  2019-12-13 11:58:36.836  INFO 16796 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet            : ChangeSet classpath:/db/db.changelog.xml::1::GerdAschemann ran successfully in 3ms
  2019-12-13 11:58:36.837  INFO 16796 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT MAX(ORDEREXECUTED) FROM PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
  2019-12-13 11:58:36.840  INFO 16796 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : INSERT INTO PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES ('1', 'GerdAschemann', 'classpath:/db/db.changelog.xml', NOW(), 1, '8:c491fb651a899536b626ee5370713ff7', 'createSequence sequenceName=xxx_sequence; createTable tableName=xxx_entity', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '3.8.2', '6234716828')
  2019-12-13 11:58:36.850  INFO 16796 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Successfully released change log lock
  2019-12-13 11:58:36.947  INFO 16796 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
  2019-12-13 11:58:37.007  INFO 16796 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.9.Final}
  2019-12-13 11:58:37.152  INFO 16796 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
  2019-12-13 11:58:37.251  INFO 16796 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  2019-12-13 11:58:37.456  WARN 16796 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=net.aschemann.demo.spring.boot.hibernateproblem.XxxEntity]
  2019-12-13 11:58:37.456  INFO 16796 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
  2019-12-13 11:58:37.458  INFO 16796 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
  2019-12-13 11:58:37.465  INFO 16796 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
  2019-12-13 11:58:37.475 ERROR 16796 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=net.aschemann.demo.spring.boot.hibernateproblem.XxxEntity]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
  at net.aschemann.demo.spring.boot.hibernateproblem.HibernateProblemApplication.main(HibernateProblemApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
  Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=net.aschemann.demo.spring.boot.hibernateproblem.XxxEntity]
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  ... 15 common frames omitted
  Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=net.aschemann.demo.spring.boot.hibernateproblem.XxxEntity]
  at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
  at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createIdentifierGenerator(SimpleValue.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.lambda$new$1(SessionFactoryImpl.java:292) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
  at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_192-ea]
  at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_192-ea]
  at java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1628) ~[na:1.8.0_192-ea]
  at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_192-ea]
  at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_192-ea]
  at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:1.8.0_192-ea]
  at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:1.8.0_192-ea]
  at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_192-ea]
  at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_192-ea]
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:291) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
  at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
  ... 19 common frames omitted
  Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: The increment size of the [XXX_SEQUENCE] sequence is set to [10] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1].
  at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.configure(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
  at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
  ... 36 common frames omitted
  Process finished with exit code 1
  ```

Comment: Is the sequence generated by Hibernate? If not, what does it look like if you let Hibernate generate it? Is the exception thrown during schema validation? How do the ids get generated if you disable schema validation?

Comment: Strange, it looks like it's coming from validation but of course that should make the exception go away. Please log the full stack trace and post it here.

Comment: Falling back to HB 5.3 fixes the problem: https://github.com/ascheman/hibernate-so-59305427/tree/fix-w-hibernate-5.3

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. I'd open a ticket with Hibernte.

Comment: Raised https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13783

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue, you can fix it with the following annotation in the id field:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "hilo_sequence_generator", allocationSize = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think  if you change @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "10") to @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1") this will work. why do you want to set the value as 10?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was working on migrating a legacy application that was still using hbm.xml files. I added the following to the `<id/>` section and it fixed it.

```xml
<param name="increment_size">1</param>
```

It looks something like this:

```xml
<id name="tableId" type="java.lang.Long" column="TABLE_ID">
    <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">TABLE_ID_SEQ</param>
        <param name="increment_size">1</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```