# JPA sequence generator says increment size differs from the value in DB

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

```
@Table(name = "CACHING_DATA")
@Entity
public class CachingData implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CACHING_SEQUENCE")
    private Long id;
    private String protocolecode;
    private String uuid;
}
```

[image: Sequence used]

I have above entity class and oracle sequence. But I am getting following error.

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: The increment size of the [CACHING_SEQUENCE] sequence is set to [50] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxSKJ.png).

Comment: Drop and recreate the database, might be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use allocationSize = 1 for the sequence

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SomeNameForTheGenerator", sequenceName = "CACHING_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
```

here the samish issue: [org.hibernate.MappingException: The increment size of the sequence is set to [10] in the entity mapping while ... size is [1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305427/org-hibernate-mappingexception-the-increment-size-of-the-sequence-is-set-to-10)

Comment: Any idea what that would look like as .hbm.xml?